# Moving to forms in Windows Phone 8.1 throws "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, access-denied

I created an Windows Phone 8.1 application (C#), that basically navigates me to another form where a map view is displayed. Problematic code being a button click event:

```
        public void ToOriginal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.MapPage));
      //Pages is a folder where all pages are put in. MapPage is what I open
    }
```

Also using is in place:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
```

The exception thrown:

```
Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

I added the Location capability in the Package.appxmanifest. It worked before at some point, but did I change something, that caused this now?

I searched around, but didn't find anything similar. Same codes, but different reasons. Seems like this is a general exception code thrown when something is denied. But how to solve this navigation one?

If anyone can link me to the answer or have info about this, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was having this problem
Replace
`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.MapPage));`
With

```
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
               Frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.MapPage)));
```

That should fix the issue

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix my issue. Did You add anything extra in the appxmanifest other than just ticking off the Location capability?

Comment: I didnt tick off location but instead replaced the navigation line with the Dispatcher.RunAsync line